# KeyBoard Hides the EditText

Tags: android, android-fragments

```
   getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_LAYOUT_NO_LIMITS, WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_LAYOUT_NO_LIMITS);

      InputMethodManager inputMethodManager = (InputMethodManager) getActivity().getSystemService(Activity.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
            inputMethodManager.hideSoftInputFromWindow(view.getWindowToken(), 0);

    @Override
        public void onResume() {
            super.onResume();
            mView.getViewTreeObserver().addOnGlobalLayoutListener(new ViewTreeObserver.OnGlobalLayoutListener() {
                @Override
                public void onGlobalLayout() {
                    Rect r = new Rect();
                    mView.getWindowVisibleDisplayFrame(r);
                    int heightDiff = mView.getRootView().getHeight() - (r.bottom - r.top);

                    if (heightDiff > 100) { // if more than 100 pixels, its probably a keyboard...
                        //ok now we know the keyboard is up...
                        mView.findViewById(R.id.txt_error_message).setVisibility(View.GONE);
                        mView.findViewById(R.id.btn_user_signup).setVisibility(View.GONE);
                    } else {
                        //ok now we know the keyboard is down...
                        mView.findViewById(R.id.txt_error_message).setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                        mView.findViewById(R.id.btn_user_signup).setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

                    }
                }
            });

        }


< LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/frag_cont_registration"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@android:color/transparent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    tools:context="com.apps.robo.fragments.FragmentItcRegistration">

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/input_phone_email"
        android:layout_width="218dp"
        android:layout_height="45dp"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:layout_marginTop="36dp"
        android:background="@drawable/edit_text_border_bottom"
        android:fontFamily="@string/light_roboto"
        android:gravity="bottom|center"
        android:hint="@string/hint_enter_phone_number"
        android:inputType="number"
        android:maxLines="1"
        android:textColor="@android:color/white"
        android:textColorHint="@android:color/white"
        android:textSize="14sp"
        android:cursorVisible="true"/>
    <!-- android:singleLine="true" -->

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/txt_error_message"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="38dp"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:fontFamily="@string/light_roboto"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="@string/enter_email"
        android:textColor="@android:color/white"
        android:textSize="15sp"
        android:visibility="gone" />


    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btn_user_signup"
        android:layout_width="218dp"
        android:layout_height="38dp"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:layout_marginTop="24sp"
        android:background="@drawable/bg_buttton_white_border"
        android:fontFamily="@string/medium_roboto"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="@string/btn_label_submit"
        android:textAllCaps="false"
        android:textColor="@color/white"
        android:textSize="15sp" />
</LinearLayout>
```

well nothing works. note activity is fullScreen and
   tried with scrollview too, and cannot change the design. and EditText is the fragment. full screen fragment also not working.  Hiding views doesnot work in Lollypop but works in kitkat.

Comment: Show your work please .

Comment: what about `android:windowSoftInputMode="stateHidden|adjustPan"`

Comment: Welcome to SO, please be a bit more specific when asking question: what have you tried, what do you expect, etc. See [how to ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: Thanks Amiya But its not working.

Comment: can you please write xml file and screenshot of output ?

Comment: try  android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize" , it works for me

Comment: Thank you Amee joshi but it wont work for me.

Comment: It works finely for the first time but when i click again it hides

Answer (score 1):

adjustPan not working with WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_LAYOUT_NO_LIMITS

try this:

```
        getWindow().addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
        getWindow().clearFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FORCE_NOT_FULLSCREEN);
```

or this:

```
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT) {
        Window w = getWindow();
        getWindow().addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
        w.getDecorView().setSystemUiVisibility(
                View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_STABLE
                        | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_FULLSCREEN);
    }

    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
        getWindow().setStatusBarColor(Color.TRANSPARENT);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

**Try this:**

`android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan" >`

Answer (score 0):

add this line in your activity manifest.

```
<activity android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize"> </activity>
```

or add

`<activity android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan"> </activity>`

as Rohit Arya suggests

**NOTE :**

After doing a lot of searching i found this. If you use the fullscreen tag (to remove the status bar from the activity) you can't use "adjustResize" without wrapping the activity in a ScrollView.

try this

**EXAMPLE**

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 <ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
   android:layout_width="match_parent"
   android:layout_height="match_parent" >  
     ...

     ...

  </ScrollView>
```

Comment: i edited my answer try this once and let me know it works

Comment: No its not working, actually its working fine for first click. when i attempt second time the layout wont scroll! (LollyPop device)

Comment: try changing ScrollViews height to wrap_content and its children layouts height to wrap_content

Answer (score 0):

Try adding this `android:windowSoftInputMode="stateHidden|adjustPan"` to the manifest file inside the activity tags of the "Activity" you're having an issue with.

**For instance:**

```
<activity
     android:name=".ContactActivity"
     android:label="@string/title_activity_contact"
     android:screenOrientation="portrait"
     android:windowSoftInputMode="stateHidden|adjustPan" >
</activity>
```